# sqlite3: command not found Python 3 on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I installed Python 3.6.5 on Windows 10. I see that there is a sqlite3 folder in ...\Python\Python36\Lib directory. I added Python PATH to environment variable. However, I can't run the command "sqlite3" from Powershell nor Git Bash. It would say "command not found". What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's sqlite library probably is installed. Try: `import sqlite3` in the Python shell.

If you want to be able to use sqlite's CLI program, you need to install it.

Download [here](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html). Use the Windows version obviously.

Comment: I tried import sqlite3 it produced no error. I assume the library is installed. I thought sqlite3 CLI program is included with Python 3. I will try to install the sqlite-tools-win32-x86 tool from the link provided. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnFisher It did

Comment: I have sqlite3 already installed on mac, but it doesn't have all the dot commands, and I need .load to follow a tutorial. How can I get .load command for my sqlite3?

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of the folder where python3 is installed, it may be that when using powershell you do not have the necessary permissions to access them.

It is always highly recommended to install python3 in a route **WITHOUT SPACES**

like a:

```
C:\python36
```

Comment: My python path is C:\Python\Python36 . Permissions are good. I've been running pip, virtualenv, python and other commands. However, when I try to run the command "sqlite3 database.db < schema.sql", I got error that command is not found.

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently Sqlite3's CLI does not come installed with Python (Python 3.6). What comes pre-installed is Python's Sqlite3 library.So, you can access the Sqlite3 DB either through the library, or by manually installing Sqlite3 CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with installing brotab, and I always got the message that sqlite3 was not found. I had just installed python beforehand, and in list of modules, I saw sqlite3. When I started py.exe console, I also could import that module. It turned out that I had a entry in my Path to `c:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program`, which contained an older version of `python.exe`.

I ran `python.exe -m pydoc -b` inside that program folder to see the Index of modules, and there was no mention of sqlite3. I removed that entry from my Path, and kept the newly installed python.exe, and it fixed the issue