# bash: sqlite3: command not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Apparently it is supposed to be part of Python3 but it says "bash: sqlite3: command not found".

I'm so new to all of this and I'm just trying to follow along with a tutorial on youtube. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: No, it's not part of Python.

Comment: which OS are you on? here is somewhere to start for Windows 10:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205804/sqlite3-command-not-found-python-3-on-windows-10

From that thread: "So, apparently Sqlite3's CLI does not come installed with Python (Python 3.6). What comes pre-installed is Python's Sqlite3 library.So, you can access the Sqlite3 DB either through the library, or by manually installing Sqlite3 CLI."

Comment: I'm running windows 10, I saw that thread already. It didn't help. The guy above said it didn't install with Python probably so I guess I'll install it on its own.

Comment: was in my answer comment but in case you can't find it:

sqlitetutorial.net/download-install-sqlite

Answer (score 7):

On Linux (or in a Docker container running a Linux OS variant), you can install the command line interface via `sudo apt-get install sqlite3` and then run `sqlite3`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to download the command line interface here if you want to do stuff in bash:

https://sqlite.org/download.html

Do the binaries for your OS and then just follow the instructions. You might need a program to unzip them like:

https://www.7-zip.org/

Python comes with a library for sqlite that you can import into a .py program with

```
import sqlite3
```

that you can read about here, https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html, but that's a thing you do inside of a python program.

Comment: so I've created an environment and created an .sql file. The next step in the tutorial is "$ sqlite3 database.db < schema.sql" but it says command not found. I'll look though your links. I may be in a bit over my head.


Do you know where I would extract the files for sqlite3? I put them in a new folder "C:\SQLite3" but I'm still not having luck.

Comment: follow along here since you're on windows: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/download-install-sqlite/

Put the files in a new folder like: 

First, create a new folder e.g., C:\sqlite.
Second, extract the content of the file that you downloaded in the previous section to the C:\sqlite folder. You should see three programs in the C:\sqlite folder as shown below:


Then type this in terminal: 

C:\cd c:\sqlite
C:\sqlite>sqlite3

Comment: This video also looks decent: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZ20Lh4zbRo

Try to find videos in your OS, your original post had bash shell not found which is in OS X/Linux so that makes it a pain already. 

If you really want, you can install WSL2 to run linux commands in windows:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=av0UQy6g2FA

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10